# Erro ao exibir informaçoes no listView Android + FireBase

Tags: android, firebase, nosql

Eu estou com dois problemas com esse programa... o primeiro é que ao cadastrar ele não entrar no primeiro laço de repetição msm estando td certinho... ele pula e exibe a mensagem "sem dados", o segundo problema é que dps de clicar no botão de cadastro ele insere os dados no BD porem não os exibe no listView... Eu revisei o codigo fiz algumas mudanças e não consegui resolver.

Agradeço desde já a ajuda...

//Classe de Usuarios

```
public class Usuarios {

private String nome;
private String Data;
private String Rg;
private String Cpf;
private String Endereco;
private String Doenca;
private String Profissao;

public void Usuarios(){

}

public String getCpf() {
    return Cpf;
}

public void setCpf(String cpf) {
    Cpf = cpf;
}

public String getData() {
    return Data;
}

public void setData(String data) {
    Data = data;
}

public String getDoenca() {
    return Doenca;
}

public void setDoenca(String doenca) {
    Doenca = doenca;
}

public String getEndereco() {
    return Endereco;
}

public void setEndereco(String endereco) {
    Endereco = endereco;
}

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

public String getProfissao() {
    return Profissao;
}

public void setProfissao(String profissao) {
    Profissao = profissao;
}

public String getRg() {
    return Rg;
}

public void setRg(String rg) {
    Rg = rg;
 }
}
```

//CLasse do BD Firebase

public class FireHelper {
    DatabaseReference bd;
    boolean saved;
    ArrayList usuarioss = new ArrayList<>();

```
public FireHelper(DatabaseReference bd) {
    this.bd = bd;
}
public Boolean save(Usuarios usuarios){
    if(usuarios == null){
        saved = true;
    }
    else
    {
        try{
            bd.child("Usuarios").push().setValue(usuarios);
        }catch (DatabaseException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            saved = true;
        }
    }
    return saved;
}

private void fetchData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
    usuarioss.clear();

    for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
        Usuarios usuarios = ds.getValue(Usuarios.class);
        usuarioss.add(usuarios);
    }
}

public ArrayList<Usuarios> retorno(){
    bd.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            fetchData(dataSnapshot);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            fetchData(dataSnapshot);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    return usuarioss;
}
```

}

// Classe Main onde vai exibir os dados

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
DatabaseReference bd;
FireHelper helper;
AdapterCustom adapter;
ListView lv;
EditText textViewNome, textViewData, textViewRg, textViewCpf, textViewEndereco, textViewDoenca, textViewProfissao;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    //Banco de dados
    bd = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    helper = new FireHelper(bd);
    //layout
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
    //Adaptador
    adapter = new AdapterCustom(this, helper.retorno());
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);


    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            displayInputDialog();
        }
    });
}



private void displayInputDialog() {
    Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
    d.setTitle("Salvar no banco de dados");
    d.setContentView(R.layout.input_dialog);

    //Declarando objetos
    final TextView textViewNome = (TextView) d.findViewById(R.id.editTextNome);
    final TextView textViewData = (TextView) d.findViewById(R.id.editTextData);
    final TextView textViewRg = (TextView) d.findViewById(R.id.editTextRg);
    final TextView textViewCpf = (TextView) d.findViewById(R.id.editTextCpf);
    final TextView textViewEndereco = (TextView) d.findViewById(R.id.editTextEndereco);
    final TextView textViewDoenca = (TextView) d.findViewById(R.id.editTextDoenca);
    final TextView textViewProfissao = (TextView) d.findViewById(R.id.editTextProfissao);

    Button saveButton = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.savebutton);


    //Salvar...
    saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String nome = textViewNome.getText().toString();
            String data = textViewData.getText().toString();
            String rg = textViewRg.getText().toString();
            String cpf = textViewCpf.getText().toString();
            String endereco = textViewEndereco.getText().toString();
            String doenca = textViewDoenca.getText().toString();
            String profissao = textViewProfissao.getText().toString();
            Usuarios u = new Usuarios();
            u.setNome(nome);
            u.setData(data);
            u.setRg(rg);
            u.setCpf(cpf);
            u.setEndereco(endereco);
            u.setDoenca(doenca);
            u.setProfissao(profissao);

            if (nome != null && nome.length() > 0) {
                if (helper.save(u)) {
                    textViewNome.setText("");
                    textViewData.setText("");
                    textViewRg.setText("");
                    textViewCpf.setText("");
                    textViewEndereco.setText("");
                    textViewDoenca.setText("");
                    textViewProfissao.setText("");

                    adapter = new AdapterCustom(MainActivity.this, helper.retorno());
                    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "sem dados", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    d.show();
  }

}
```

//Classe do Adapter

```
public class AdapterCustom extends BaseAdapter {
Context c;
ArrayList<Usuarios> usuarioss;

public AdapterCustom(Context c, ArrayList<Usuarios> usuarioss) {
    this.c = c;
    this.usuarioss = usuarioss;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return usuarioss.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return usuarioss.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView== null){
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.model,parent,false);
    }
    //Declarando objetos
    TextView textViewNome = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewNome);
    TextView textViewData = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewData);
    TextView textViewRg = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRg);
    TextView textViewCpf = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCpf);
    TextView textViewEndereco = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewEndereco);
    TextView textViewDoenca = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDoenca);
    TextView textViewProfissao = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewProfissao);

    final Usuarios u = (Usuarios) this.getItem(position);

    textViewNome.setText(u.getNome());
    textViewData.setText(u.getData());
    textViewRg.setText(u.getRg());
    textViewCpf.setText(u.getCpf());
    textViewEndereco.setText(u.getEndereco());
    textViewDoenca.setText(u.getDoenca());
    textViewProfissao.setText(u.getProfissao());

    //Função onclick

    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(c, u.getNome(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });



    return convertView;
 }
}
```

Comment: aconselho vc a fazer esse curso, me ajudou muito https://www.udacity.com/course/firebase-in-a-weekend-by-google-android--ud0352?product=5483321653723136&_ga=1.33938472.843565695.1438022865%3Futm_source%3Dblog&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=sb_widget_enroll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O firebase ocorre em segundo plano (assincronia) enquanto seu código ainda executa. voce não pode inserir/pegar dados no firebase e na linha de baixo já dar return em alguma coisa pq os métodos de busca e inserção ainda não acabaram de executar, pq eles têm que esperar a resposta do servidor...

O firebase tem um método chamado addOnSucessListener que ouve se o resultado foi bem ou mal sucedido.
Voce deve deixar todo o código que deve ser executado após a busca/inserção de dados dentro desse método(ele vai ser chamado automaticamente após o firebase inserir/buscar dados. Por confiar).

Ex enviar dados:

```
    String cod = ref.child("POSTS").push().getKey();
    ref.child("POSTS").child(cod).setValue(postObjeto)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Chegou", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            //aqui vai ser o método caso os dados foram inseridos com SUCESSO
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Erro "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
```

Ex pegar dados:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
ref.child("POSTS").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
              if(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()==0){
              //se tá vazio o banco sai do método de busca
               }else{
                      for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {//para cada postagem no banco, cria um objeto e add numa lista...
                        Postagem p = postSnapshot.getValue(Postagem.class);
                        listagemPostagens.add(p);
                    }
                }
                setRecyclerView(listagemPostagens);// somente após os dados chegarem de fato...
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
//caso for cancelado a busca...
            }
        });
```